# Why do videos not play when Bluetooth headphones are connected?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, headphones

I have Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and Sony WH-1000 XM2 headphones. They worked with my computer before, but today I noticed that Amazon Video and YouTube don't play videos when the headphones are connected via Bluetooth. I have no idea why / how to investigate the problem.

When I turn them off, the videos start playing immediately.

What is going on / how can I investigate the problem?